# Cannot create rounded corners on object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I am following this tutorial to get some inspiration:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/logo-design.html?set=illustrator--get-started--ready-to-use

I used steps from the fourth video to make an object with rounded corners but i have a little issue with this. If i try to make rounded corners with the method used in video I cannot do it.

[image: Shape without rounded corners]

Also, why do I not see this tool?

[image: Missing tool]

Comment: What version of Illustrator are you using?

Answer (score 2):

you can round any corner using older Version of Illustrator by various ways.

1. By using `Appearance panel` choose `choose Effect > Stylize > Round Corners`
2. By using a Script called [Round Any Corner](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/legacy/articles/2010/article_illustrator_plugin_scripts/scripts/RoundAnyCorner.zip) Created by Hiroyuki Sato.
3. By using a plugin by Astute Graphics called [VectorScrib](http://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) as sub command called "Dynamic Corners Tool"

[image]

4. by Using the old way as follow

- Draw you shape;
- in every corner you want to make it round add one anchor two anchors as show
  by using `Add anchor point tool` or just press <kbd>+</kbd>

[image]

- delete the corner anchor by selecting it with the white arrow and delete is by selecting `Remove selected anchor points` from the properties bar. [image]
- we have just chambered the corner, and to make the cure use the `Anchor Point Tool` or just click <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and select the chambered side and drag it the a reasonable position to give you the desired cure. a perfect curve have an orthographic direction of its handles. that's mean the handels must be extended from the two segments.

[image]

- For Perfect Curvature, make a guide line and snap the handles over it.

[image]

That's it

Comment: Just pointing out that your link "Round Any Corner" doesn't work. It ends with a ] and when removing it, the link works.

Comment: @codeve fixed ... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using an older version of Illustrator.

**[Live Corners](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html)**—The ability to create and edit rounded corners on an existing shape, is only available in Illustrator CC.

The tool you are missing is the **[Curvature Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/curvature-tool.html)**. The Curvature Tool is designed to simplify path creation and make drawing curves easy—Also only available in Illustrator CC (introduced in CC-2014).